# Rescale the next system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

We have the following system (prey-predator):
\begin{cases} 
      h'=rh-\frac{\alpha h}{1+\beta h}p & \\
      p'=-ap+\frac{\gamma h}{1+\beta h}p & 
   \end{cases}
I have to rewrite it so that it looks as simple as possible.
I did the following:

1. $h=\bar{h}H$;
2. $p=\bar{p}P$;
3. $t=\bar{t}\tau.$

After that I got the system:

\begin{cases} 
      H'=H-\frac{HP}{1+H} & \\
      P'=-\frac{a}{r}P+\frac{\frac{\gamma}{r\beta}}{1+H}HP & 
   \end{cases}
I got these because I did the notations: $\bar{t}=\frac{1}{r},\bar{p}=\frac{r}{\alpha} $ and $\bar{h}=\frac{1}{\beta}.$

Is it correct what I did? or did I not choose the right notations?

Comment: This looks good. You used all the degrees of freedom, so you could shuffle the simplifications around, but will always end up with two non-trivial constants.

Comment: would there be another scaling method to better show this equation?